# How do you sort an array in alphabetical order?

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

I was given an assignment from my Java textbook to sort an array of CD names in alphabetical order. The assignment says:

Change the Tunes program (Listing 6.7) so that it keeps the CDs sorted by title. Use the general object sort defined in the Sorts class from this chapter.

Here is the Listing 6.7:

```
//********************************************************************
//  Tunes.java       Author: Lewis/Loftus/Cocking
//
//  Driver for demonstrating the use of an array of objects.
//********************************************************************

public class Tunes {
   //-----------------------------------------------------------------
   //  Creates a CDCollection object and adds some CDs to it. Prints
   //  reports on the status of the collection.
   //-----------------------------------------------------------------
   public static void main (String[] args) {
      CDCollection music = new CDCollection ();

      music.addCD ("By the Way", "Red Hot Chili Peppers", 14.95, 10);
      music.addCD ("Come On Over", "Shania Twain", 14.95, 16);
      music.addCD ("Soundtrack", "The Producers", 17.95, 33);
      music.addCD ("Play", "Jennifer Lopez", 13.90, 11);

      System.out.println (music);

      music.addCD ("Double Live", "Garth Brooks", 19.99, 26);
      music.addCD ("Greatest Hits", "Stone Temple Pilots", 15.95, 13);

      System.out.println (music);
   }
}
```

I am not sure how I can use letters in alphabetical order to sort. I did create and organize the CD's into an array of numbers though just to see how it would look:

```
//********************************************************************
//  Tunes.java       Author: Lewis/Loftus/Cocking
//
//  Driver for demonstrating the use of an array of objects.
//********************************************************************

public class Tunes {
   //-----------------------------------------------------------------
   //  Creates a CDCollection object and adds some CDs to it. Prints
   //  reports on the status of the collection.
   //-----------------------------------------------------------------
   public static void main (String[] args) {
      CDCollection[] music = new CDCollection[5];

      music[0] = new CDCollection ("By the Way", "Red Hot Chili Peppers", 14.95, 10);
      music[1] = new CDCollection ("Come On Over", "Shania Twain", 14.95, 16);
      music[2] = new CDCollection ("Soundtrack", "The Producers", 17.95, 33);
      music[3] = new CDCollection ("Play", "Jennifer Lopez", 13.90, 11);

      System.out.println (music);

      music[4] = new CDCollection ("Double Live", "Garth Brooks", 19.99, 26);
      music[5] = new CDCollection ("Greatest Hits", "Stone Temple Pilots", 15.95, 13);

      System.out.println (music);
   }
}
```

Here is the sort class that includes Selection and Insertion sort methods:

```
//********************************************************************
//  Sorts.java       Author: Lewis/Loftus/Cocking
//
//  Demonstrates the selection sort and insertion sort algorithms,
//  as well as a generic object sort.
//********************************************************************

public class Sort {
   //-----------------------------------------------------------------
   //  Sorts the specified array of integers using the selection
   //  sort algorithm.
   //-----------------------------------------------------------------
   public static void selectionSort (int[] numbers) {
      int min, temp;

      for (int index = 0; index < numbers.length-1; index++) {
         min = index;
         for (int scan = index+1; scan < numbers.length; scan++)
            if (numbers[scan] < numbers[min])
               min = scan;

         // Swap the values
         temp = numbers[min];
         numbers[min] = numbers[index];
         numbers[index] = temp;
      }
   }

   //-----------------------------------------------------------------
   //  Sorts the specified array of integers using the insertion
   //  sort algorithm.
   //-----------------------------------------------------------------
   public static void insertionSort (int[] numbers) {
      for (int index = 1; index < numbers.length; index++) {
         int key = numbers[index];
         int position = index;

         // shift larger values to the right
         while (position > 0 && numbers[position-1] > key) {
            numbers[position] = numbers[position-1];
            position--;
         }

         numbers[position] = key;
      }
   }

   //-----------------------------------------------------------------
   //  Sorts the specified array of objects using the insertion
   //  sort algorithm.
   //-----------------------------------------------------------------
   public static void insertionSort (Comparable[] objects) {
      for (int index = 1; index < objects.length; index++) {
         Comparable key = objects[index];
         int position = index;

         // shift larger values to the right
         while (position > 0 && objects[position-1].compareTo(key) > 0) {
            objects[position] = objects[position-1];
            position--;
         }

         objects[position] = key;
      }
   }
}
```

I am just not sure what to do to all sorting with letters instead of numbers. Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236/18157) and 
[Open letter to students with homework problems](http://meta.softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/6166/989)

Answer (score 1):

The way to go for this is `Sort#insertionSort(Comparable[])`.

A `String` provides the method [String#compareTo(String)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/index.html?java/lang/String.html), since it implements the interface [`Comparable<String>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html). This method is created in a way to sort Strings lexicographically.

So simply passing the array to `Sort#insertionSort(Comparable[])` should solve the problem for you. How this works should be explained later on in the book (at least I hope so).

Answer (score 1):

You can implement the Comparable interface and compare Title in the compareTo method, then Collections.sort() will do the trick for you:

```
public class CDItem implements Comparable<CDItem>{
    String title;
    String singer;
    double price;

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }
    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }
    public String getSinger() {
        return singer;
    }
    public void setSinger(String singer) {
        this.singer = singer;
    }
    public double getPrice() {
        return price;
    }
    public void setPrice(double price) {
        this.price = price;
    }

    CDItem(String title, String singer, double price){
        this.title=title;
        this.singer=singer;
        this.price=price;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(CDItem item){
        return this.title.compareTo(item.title);
    }
}

public class CDCollection{
    List<CDItem> list=new ArrayList<CDItem>();

    public void addCD(String title, String singer, double price){
        CDItem item=new CDItem(title, singer, price);
        list.add(item);
    }

    public String toString(){
        String result="";
        for(int i=0; i<list.size(); i++){
            CDItem item=(CDItem)list.get(i);
            result=result + "|" + item.getTitle(); 
        }

        return result;
    }

    public void sort(){
        Collections.sort(list);
    }
}
```

then add the last two lines in your Tunes class:

```
public class Tunes {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        CDCollection music = new CDCollection ();

        music.addCD ("By the Way", "Red Hot Chili Peppers", 14.95);
        music.addCD ("Come On Over", "Shania Twain", 14.95);
        music.addCD ("Soundtrack", "The Producers", 17.95);
        music.addCD ("Play", "Jennifer Lopez", 13.90);

        System.out.println (music);

        music.addCD ("Double Live", "Garth Brooks", 19.99);
        music.addCD ("Greatest Hits", "Stone Temple Pilots", 15.95);

        System.out.println (music);

        music.sort();
        System.out.println (music);
    }   
}
```